# Face ID is disabled

Tags: ios, face-id

I use biometric in my application. Users say that Face ID is disabled if the application is not used for about 3 days. After entering the password, the face ID becomes available again. Are there any Apple restrictions when not using the application for a long time? Thank you.

Comment: There are no restrictions on a per-app basis. The restrictions are applied on the device as @CBroe stated

Answer (score 1):

https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT208108:

> To use Face ID, you must set up a passcode on your device. You must enter your passcode for additional security validation when:
>
> - The device has just been turned on or restarted.
> - **The device hasn’t been unlocked for more than 48 hours.**
> - The passcode hasn’t been used to unlock the device in the last six and a half days and Face ID hasn't unlocked the device in the last 4 hours.
> - The device has received a remote lock command.
> - After five unsuccessful attempts to match a face.
> - After initiating power off / Emergency SOS by pressing and holding either volume button and the side button simultaneously for 2 seconds.